# Создание образа Docker из windows проблема с путями

Tags: django, docker

Создаю проект в директории

```
pwd
/c/docker/docker-project/python
```

из Dockerfile

```
From python:3
RUN pip install django
RUN mkdir /data
WORKDIR /data
```

запускаю его

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/data --rm -it my_django django-admin.py startproject my_app
```

В контейнере, указанная директория и проект создались, а в вот в windows,  файлы проекта не появились кроме Dockerfile ничего нету

```
ls -l
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 vs 197121 69 янв 25 12:56 Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. В ос windows, чтобы создавались общие директории проектов, они должны находится по пути с:\Users\UserName...